# Possible bug in attribute ordering for QGIS 2.16.0-Nødebo?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-2.16

I recently downloaded QGIS 2.16.0-Nødebo and noticed the ascending/descending ordering of the attribute table has changed (tested with **integer**, **integer64**, **real** and **string** type fields). Couldn't find a bug report for this so thought I would ask here if anyone has experienced this before I add a report?

- Ascending order:

  [image: Ascending order]
- Descending order:

  [image: Descending order]

Comment: Maybe type of data in column is not a numeric type?

Comment: @W.Tom - The field shown is normal integer type, I tested with integer64, real and string and still the same result.

Comment: I just tested a layer in Nodebo and a long integer field sorted as if it was a text "number".  The same field in ArcGIS sorted as one would expect a number to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the issue in 2.16.1 and the current development version. Here's the ticket https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15366

It's fixed now and will be in the upcoming releases: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/ea0f4da58c87bc590f8b23049da0963ee9d9cd23